# make circle image acording to screen size with css

Tags: css, ionic-framework, circleimage

I am trying to make my images to circle.despite this image has different width and height, I want it to be circle that seems like they have same width and height length.
For example; dimension of my image : 250X300.
but I want it to be 200X200 circle.actually I can do this easily.the problem is doing this acording to screen size.when I turn my mobile phone to horizontal, it must change acording to screen dimensions.

my css code is below

```
.image {
     height: 100px; 
     width: 100px; 
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: use `vw` units. They are dependent on viewport-width. so, it can be like `width: 2vw;height:2vw;` Circle width will depend upon the device width. And as you are working on Mobile devices. So, there won't be any support issue as well.

Comment: actualy, I am not good at css but,it seems like it may help me.let me try this

Comment: Yeah, no problem, just replace your `px` units with `vw` and check.. depending upon that you can set, how much value you want, say `5vw` or `50vw`. Remember **1vw = 1% of viewport width**

Comment: I got it @DeepakYadav thank you so much :)

Comment: Thats great. I have posted it as answer again. So if it worked, you can mark it as accepted answer and close this question.

Comment: for sure , thank you aga'n! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use vw units. They are dependent on viewport-width. so, it can be like width: 2vw;height:2vw; Circle width will depend upon the device width.

```css
.image {
     height: 5vw; 
     width: 5vw; 
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: I think this answer is missing an `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

For >ionic2

```
<ion-card text-center class="hide-card">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="custom-avatar"/>
    <h2>Victorcodex</h2>
    <p>Have some p tag here</p>
    <p>I am the third guy inline here</p>
    <hr>
</ion-card>

.hide-card {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
}

.custom-avatar {
  height: 30vw;
  width: 30vw;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image: ionic2 side menu with centered image and text]

Kindly lemme know if this was useful to you.

Comment: You should put some strees on the `vw` part ;)

Comment: vw is the Viewport Width.

Kindly read more here https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Answer (score 0):

brother use  background-size: 100% 100%;
 your style will be like

```
 div { 
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

demo link:
http://jsfiddle.net/vNh8t/314/

Comment: bro,it's okay but when I shrink or enlarge my screen, it must extend with same ratio..

Comment: friend when you add background-size: 100% 100%; in your div class  then size increase wrt to screen resolution ratio you can test with ctrl + "+" button you can also check my jsfiddle example

Comment: I tried vw instead px.," Deepak Yadav ".I think I found the solution. thank you bro :)   link : http://jsfiddle.net/r43LL1ny/

Comment: great thats cool brother good luck for your remaining project :)