# How can I make the profile image view in Ionic framework?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to add circle view on my profile screen in my Ionic 2 project.
Is there any simple way to do that or what tag can I use in **Ionic framework** ?
Thank you.

Comment: This link  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093892/make-circle-image-acording-to-screen-size-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css below. If you want a circle that seems like they have same width and height lengt. so, it can be like width: 2vw;height:2vw; Circle width will depend upon the device width.

```
.image {
     height: 5vw; 
     width: 5vw; 
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
} 

<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a circle image view in my project so it's code is here,

**profile.html**

```
 <div class="bg-image">
  <ion-img src="data:image/*;base64,{{src}}" class="round-image" 
style="
  height: 150px !important;
  width: 150px !important;
  margin-top: 12%;
  background: none !important;
  background-color :none !important;" (click)="presentActionSheet()">
 </ion-img>
</div>
```

**profile.scss**

```
 .bg-image {
    background-color: #F7556D;
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.round-image img{
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is both file and it looks like this
[image]